# ASP.NET custom routes breaking images and javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 app and it works fine when using the default routes. So I have urls similar to this, **localhost:4457/Users/Details/5** 
I want to add a friendly slug to the url to make it **localhost:4457/Users/Details/5/some-ones-name**.
So I added a custom route and my routes now look like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "withslug",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional });

 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

On the view I have an action link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name,"Details","Users", new { id=Model.ID, slug="some-ones-name"},null)
```

I also have image links like this

`<img src="../../Content/images/picture.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="37" />`

The link works okay and when I click it follows correctly. The address reads **localhost:4457/Users/Details/5/some-ones-name**. The problem is all the images on the page are now broken and my javascript functions won't run. 
If I remove the slug from the address and just leave the url as **localhost:4457/Users/Details/5** everything works as expected.

If I add even a slash after the id, everything breaks again. The content loads as expected though, just the images and some javascript functions.

I don't understand what the problem is and any insight will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slug is being treated as a directory. You would need to add an extra `../` to the image path for it to work when the url contains a slug. You should really avoid using relative paths like that on your website.

### How to fix it so that it works on every page

You could change it to use a path that is relative to the site root like so:

```
<img src="/Content/images/picture.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="37" />
```

Or you could use a helper method that is available with asp.net mvc, it works like this. This method will auto-magically translate the path relative to the current url.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/picture.jpg")" ... />
```

This will work with `<script>` and `<link>` tags as well as any other tag which references a url.

**NOTE:** I am using Razor syntax above, if you are using the web forms view engine the code would look like this.

```
<img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/images/picture.jpg") %>" ... />
```

***Additional note**, I feel dirty having just written the `<% %>` tags after having used razor for a few months.*

Comment: Thank you. I had mixed Url.Content and in other parts used ../../. I changed everything to Url.Content and it works like magic. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I'm using Spark with custom bindings and defining a common script location. My syntax is `<Script src="myscript.js" />` Could do the same thing for images. :) http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/bindings

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to just use absolute paths for your images and JavaScript e.g.

```
<img src="/Content/images/picture.jpg" alt="" />
```

That way, if you need to modify your URL routes again you won't have to worry about breaking any relative paths to images, CSS or JavaScript again.

The [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) method might come in useful for generating your absolute paths:

```
<img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/images/picture.jpg") %>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use relative paths, if at all possible.  Use this instead:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/images/picture.jpg")%>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a routing expert yet, but I wonder if your problem is having two adjacent optional elements.  How can the route engine distinguish between a route missing the {id} and one missing the {slug}?  What about changing the route to something like `{controller}/{action}/{id}-{slug}`?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use:

```
<img src="../../../images/logo.png" />
```

And you can access images from all levels